# Pagination issue with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using **NHibernate/Fluent NHibernate** latest versions in an MVC 4 application. I installed `Fluent NHibernate` through Nuget and the version of it is `1.3.0.733`. The version of NHibernate is something like `3.3.x`

> PM> Install-Package FluentNHibernate

Note that, the problem not occurs when I install `Fluent NHibernate` version 1.2.0.712.

> PM> Install-Package FluentNHibernate -Version 1.2.0.712

I've a query like this,

```
public IList<Post> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize)
{
  return _session.Query<Post>()
                 .Where(p => p.Published)
                 .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostedOn)
                 .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                 .Take(pageSize)
                 .Fetch(p => p.Category)
                 .FetchMany(p => p.Tags)
                 .ToList();
}
```

There are three classes are there: `Post`, `Category` and `Tag`. In the database I've 15 records for `Post`. When I pass `pageNo` as 0 and `pageSize` as 10 I'm getting only 7 records from the above query. Why?

Here are the classes and their corresponding mapping classes.

**Post**

```
  public class Post
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Published
    { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime PostedOn
    { get; set; }


    public virtual Category Category
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags
    { get; set; }
  }
```

**Category**

```
  public class Category
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts
    { get; set; }
  }
```

**Tag**

```
  public class Tag
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts
    { get; set; }
  }
```

**PostMap**

```
  public class PostMap: ClassMap<Post>
  {
    public PostMap()
    {
      Id(x => x.Id);      
      Map(x => x.Published).Not.Nullable();
      Map(x => x.PostedOn).Not.Nullable();
      References(x => x.Category).Column("Category").Not.Nullable();
      HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags).Cascade.All().Table("PostTagMap");
    }
  }
```

**CategoryMap**

```
  public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
  {
    public CategoryMap()
    {
      Id(x => x.Id);
      Map(x => x.Name).Length(50).Not.Nullable();
      Map(x => x.Description).Length(200);
      HasMany(x => x.Posts).Inverse().Cascade.All().KeyColumn("Category");
    }
  }
```

**TagMap**

```
  public class TagMap: ClassMap<Tag>
  {
    public TagMap()
    {
      Id(x => x.Id);
      Map(x => x.Name).Length(50).Not.Nullable();
      Map(x => x.Description).Length(200);
      HasManyToMany(x => x.Posts).Cascade.All().Inverse().Table("PostTagMap");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just double checking: they are all definitely "Published"?

Comment: What version of NH are you using?

Comment: As a sidenote, it might be better to design you APIs to take (firstresult, maxresults) instead of (pageno, pagesize) as the former is more flexible.

Comment: @Simon yes all the posts are published

Answer (score 4):

Please, try to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13894326/1679310

The issue is most likely hidden in the inline *Fetch* of a `Tag` collection. It will results in a SELECT clause which returns more rows then the `Post` count is. And `Take()` and `Skip()` are applied on this resultset... so only first 7 Posts are returned because some of them has more Tags:

> Post1 | TagA 
>  Post2 | TagA 
>  Post2 | TagB 
>  ..

Comment: The solution would be to do a "lazy fetch" - ie. first take out the posts with skip&take. Then populate the collections by querying the Post's with the .Fetch / .FetchMany discarding the result.